# mysql: unknown option '--"' in Kubernetes

Tags: mysql, kubernetes

I am trying to run mysql 5.7 in kubernetes and got this error
`mysql: unknown option '--"'`

My database.yaml looks like this

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: app-db
  labels:
    app: app-db
spec:
  containers:
  - name: mysql
    image: mysql:5.7
    ports:
    - name: mysql-port
      containerPort: 3306
    env:
    - name: MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD
      valueFrom:
        secretKeyRef:
          name: app-secrets
          key: rootPassword
    - name: MYSQL_USER
      valueFrom:
        secretKeyRef:
          name: app-secrets
          key: username
    - name: MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD
      valueFrom:
        secretKeyRef:
          name: app-secrets
          key: password
    - name: MYSQL_DATABASE
      valueFrom:
        secretKeyRef:
          name: app-secrets
          key: defaultDatabase
```

Maybe I missed something?

I tried to switch versions, tried to use samples from the official Kubernetes site - nothing works for me.

The last logs with error:

```sh
2020-07-19 20:51:01 100 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
2020-07-19 20:51:01 100 [Note] mysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '5.6.49'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 0  MySQL Community Server (GPL)
2020-07-19 20:51:01+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Temporary server started.
Warning: Unable to load '/usr/share/zoneinfo/iso3166.tab' as time zone. Skipping it.
Warning: Unable to load '/usr/share/zoneinfo/leap-seconds.list' as time zone. Skipping it.
Warning: Unable to load '/usr/share/zoneinfo/zone.tab' as time zone. Skipping it.
Warning: Unable to load '/usr/share/zoneinfo/zone1970.tab' as time zone. Skipping it.
2020-07-19 20:51:04 100 [Warning] 'proxies_priv' entry '@ root@app-db' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
2020-07-19 20:51:04+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Creating database app_db

mysql: unknown option '--"'
```

Comment: Where are you seeing the error? Show the full log and commands used.

Comment: @AndyShinn I just did `kubectl create -f database.yaml` and then `kubectl logs -f app-db`. Then I saw that mysql i trying to start and then failed with this error

Comment: @AndyShinn I attached last logs with error

Comment: What file contains the `proxies_priv` entry which is (apparently) in error? It doesn't appear in the database.yaml file you posted above.

Comment: please give me this output `kubectl get secret app-secrets -o yaml` . Thanks !

Comment: I happened to meet the exact same problem

Answer (score 15):

I ran into the same issue and after a lot of frustrating debugging I finally solved it.

The problem was that I created my secrets with the `echo 'secret' | base64` command and the echo command automatically inserts a trailing newline.

Use `echo -n 'secret' | base64` instead. ✔️

Unfortunately this was not at all what I expected and therefore I didn't notice that there was a line break in the log output. Hopefully this can help some people who also use the echo command to encode to base64.

Comment: That was it for me, too. Thank you so much. I was about to go crazy, as i've had this issue with multiple images and tags.

Answer (score 1):

I looked at the `entrypont.sh` script for this container . And the error is happening here in the 'Creating database' section:

```sh
# Creates a custom database and user if specified
if [ -n "$MYSQL_DATABASE" ]; then
        mysql_note "Creating database ${MYSQL_DATABASE}" 
        docker_process_sql --database=mysql <<<"CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS \`$MYSQL_DATABASE\` ;" 
fi

if [ -n "$MYSQL_USER" ] && [ -n "$MYSQL_PASSWORD" ]; then
         mysql_note "Creating user ${MYSQL_USER}"
...
```

```sh
docker_process_sql() {
        passfileArgs=()
        if [ '--dont-use-mysql-root-password' = "$1" ]; then
                passfileArgs+=( "$1" )
                shift
        fi
        # args sent in can override this db, since they will be later in the command
        if [ -n "$MYSQL_DATABASE" ]; then
                set -- --database="$MYSQL_DATABASE" "$@"
        fi

        mysql --defaults-extra-file=<( _mysql_passfile "${passfileArgs[@]}") --protocol=socket -uroot -hlocalhost --socket="${SOCKET}" "$@"
}
```

I also tested with plain docker and it works fine with this:

```sh
docker run --name some-mysql -d -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=my-secret-pw -e MYSQL_DATABASE="app" -e MYSQL_USER="user1" mysql:5.7
```

So most likely there is something corrupted in your secrets .

✌️

Answer (score 0):

The YAML configuration is quite simple. I guess the problem might lie in the app-secrets.

Please disable all envs and then add one by one, which could help you find out the problem settings.

In case your secrets are not correct, you can set env directly, such as:

```
env:
  - name: MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD
    value: somePassYouLike
```

Because many add Kubernetes secrets by copying manually generated base64. Make sure no spaces after the base64 string itself copied. Go to Kubernetes dashboard to check the length of the secrets.